# Xamarin app deployment errors

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

When I create a xamarin android blank app template and try to debug the emulator pops up, but the app itself doesn't when I close it it says I have deployment errors I changes the log to debug mode, but I can't find anything wrong (I also read running in administrator mode fixes it but it didn't work for me).

Build Output : http://pastebin.com/gEyY1TZD

Comment: What are the deployment errors? Do you get a log or anything? The more details the better.

Comment: Try usb debugging. Its difficult to tell what the problem really is when there are deployment berors in emulator.

Comment: I can post the log but it just says deployment failed. I'm using the hyper-v emulators how would I go about usb debugging ?

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling the app on your device/emulator? If it is not listed in the app overview, try locating it at Settings -> Apps and delete it there. This often helps...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by going into that app and enabling developer mode (just like Imdad said) then going to build>>rebuild solution  then clean solution. then build >> rebuild "your_app_name" then clean "your_app_name " and then finally going build deploy app. Thanks everyone for helping me out.

Comment: Please put my answer as the answer(tick) if it helped. or yours. This will finish the question. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your settings inside the Android Emulator have developer mode enabled and the correct adb settings too, same goes for usb if you use that in the end.

Also, if you're using Xamarin Android Player then try using the main Android AVD Manager to emulate your apps. (and vice versa).

If it still doesn't work, then try using a physical device connected via ADB to then debug the app.